# php mysql problems

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when i inserted a € into the db it went in ok and is displayed in phpmyadmin ok but when i dump it through codeigniter it comes out as  â‚¬

what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you set the character encoding to utf-8 *everywhere*. You need to set it in the HTML of the page with the form, any PHP-files where strings are inserted into SQL, the database/tables and on the page displaying the final output.

Get just *one* of these wrong and you will have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your character encoding is not good, UTF-8 will be better. You can read more about unicode in [this great article on dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/unicode.html).

Answer (score -1):

use

```
htmlentities('€');
```

to save into the database if you need data to be displayed into html pages

Comment: That's just an in-case-nothing-else-works-and-I-don't-care-about-sanity-solution.

Comment: To search/match text in that database, you would need to also html-encode the search strings. Troublesome and error prone.